# Flurry AppCircle Integration - Duplicate Symbol FlurryAutoIncrement.o

Tags: analytics, flurry

I keep getting this error:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_FlurryAutoIncrement in /Users/game/FlurryAnalytics/ libFlurryAnalytics.a(FlurryAutoIncrement.o) and /Users/game/FlurryAppCircle/libFlurryAppCircle.a(FlurryAutoIncrement.o)
```

I've followed the guides properly. My XCode version is 3.2.5 and Flurry SDK version is 3.0.6

Comment: Does the current version of the FlurrySDK support Xcode back that far? I would double check the documents to be sure. Otherwise it sounds like you have 2 versions installed. Try deleting all your libraries and adding them back in.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Flurry analytics too? Can you check your build config? From our FAQ:

> This will occur if the -ObjC or -all_load flags are used in your
>   build configuration. These 2 flags can not be used with Flurry's
>   modular sdk. However, Apple does provide a -force_load flag that is
>   both more efficient and does not cause issue when applied to other
>   libraries your app uses (note: force_load should only be used on
>   static libraries exhibiting this behavior. It should not be applied to
>   the Flurry Libs). More details can be found in this link
>   (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1490/_index.html).

Let me know if this doesn't solve your issue.